# How to work with 2d Array in swift 3?

Tags: arrays, string, for-loop, multidimensional-array, swift3

Why doesn't this code work?? 
I have an array named answers which is an array that contains a collection of string arrays.
What I try to do here is access a single array within my 'answers' array which is denoted by the answers[count]. Then access each string value within that subArray using via subscripts.

Error message: 'subscript' is unavailable. cannot subscript String with an Int.

```
func showQuestionAndAnswer( b0: RoundedButton, b1: RoundedButton, b2: RoundedButton, b3: RoundedButton, count: Int) -> Void {
    // When a question is answered, count += 1, such that my questionsLabel will show next question in questions array, and buttons will show possible answers to choose from.

    // Set label to proper question.
    questionLabel.text = questions[count]

    // answers is of type [ [String], [String]...]
    for subArray in answers[count] {
        // answers[count] tells me which array of answers I should look into.
        // subArray should be a single array with string values.

            // Each sub array has a unique number of string values. Each value should be placed as title for resective button.
            switch subArray.count {
                case 4 :
                    b0.titleLabel?.text
                        = subArray[0]
                    b1.titleLabel?.text = subArray[1]
                    b2.titleLabel?.text = subArray[2]
                    b3.titleLabel?.text = subArray[3]
                break

                case 3 :
                    b0.titleLabel?.text = subArray[0]
                    b1.titleLabel?.text = subArray[1]
                    b2.titleLabel.text = subArray[2]
                break

                case 2 :
                    b0.titleLabel?.text = subArray[0]
                    b1.titleLabel?.text = subArray[1]

                break

                default:
                b0.titleLabel?.text = "No Answers"
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: you don't need to (and shouldn't) explicitly put `break` in Swift. Cases always break unless they're explicitly told to  `fallthrough`.

Comment: So where's the declaration of `questions`?

Comment: Well if `answers` is a `[[String]]`, then `answers[count]` is a `[String]`, thus `subArray` is a `String`, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

answers need to be [[String]] to be able to call .count on it

also you need to call

```
for subArray in answers{
}
```

Comment: @Alexander: Thanks for the tip on breaks. Declaration of answers and questions wasn't included in this snippet. The problem is that if i print subArray to the console it will provide all string values that are in the array. I just cant access values individually via subscript.

Comment: what happens if you use the for-Loop like mentioned above?

Comment: Hamish was right. I just assigned the desired array to a constant. I made things more difficult then they had to be.                                               Example:                                                                                                        let subArray = answers[count]... lol. appreciate the help though guys.

Answer (score 0):

Here as you told answers is array of string array, that means it is like this `var answers:[[string]]`

so you can iterate like following

```
for subArray in answers {
  //here subArray would of type [String]
  switch subArray.count{
    //Your code
  }
}
```

PS. Alexander is right about break statements.